# FTP Server doesn't react to USER requst

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ftp, server

I am trying to make a terminal based ftp client in python 2.7.
I set up a server (FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta) and tried to execute a script that communicates with that Server.

My Client.py:

```
import socket
import time

host = raw_input("ip ->")
port = 21

s = socket.socket()

s.connect((host, port))

print s.recv(8192)
print s.recv(8192)

s.send("USER user")
print "sent"
print s.recv(512)

s.close()
```

Client.py output:

```
ip ->localhost
220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta

220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/file

sent
421 Login time exceeded. Closing control connection.
```

Server output:

```
(000010)02.01.2017 03:45:22 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000010)02.01.2017 03:45:22 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
(000010)02.01.2017 03:45:22 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000010)02.01.2017 03:45:22 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000010)02.01.2017 03:46:22 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 421 Login time exceeded. Closing control connection.
(000010)02.01.2017 03:46:22 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

why does the server ignore my "USER user" request ?
(I'd like to code this without the help of other librarys/modules than "socket", (I am aware of the existence of ftplib, but I don't want to use it :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `\r\n` after `USER user`.

Comment: That did the trick , thank you very much :)

But why did it work ?

Comment: The FTP Server needs a delimiter (i.e. A line break) to know when the command ends. In your case, `USER user` is the command, and you need to end with `\n` to end your command.

Comment: @HansWuast: as for the 'why': there are standards you need to follow when implementing a protocol and FTP is defined in [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) so please look up there why you need the line end. And actually adding `\n` only is wrong although it works with many servers. The correct end of command would be not `\n` but `\r\n`.